# Set Order Theory: An example in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a Total Order?

Tags: order-theory

A Relation $R$ satisfying Transitivity, Reflexivity and Antisymmetry is a partial order.

Is it possible to find a partial order relation which is a  Total Order in $\mathbb{R}^2$? So, taking two elements in $\mathbb{R}^2$ I will always be able to compare then. In other words, $xRy$ and $yRx$ holds.

I just can not figure it out any example? Is it possible?

Any help guys?

Comment: Completeness allows me to compare any two elements, $x$ and $y$ in $R^{2}$ @EricTowers I edited. Thanks.

Comment: This is usually called a "total order".

Comment: `$\mathbb{R}^2$` gives $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: edited.

Comment: Oh... well, that is certainly a lot less confusing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First order by abscissa, then if those are equal, by ordinate.
$$(a,b) < (c,d) \iff (a < c) \text{ or } (a = c \text{ and } b < d)$$

Comment: [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Agreed.

Comment: So... you are reading the $R^2$ in the second paragraph as $\mathbb{R}^2$... okay, fair reading. Certainly would make much more sense than $R^2 = \bigl\{ \bigl( (a,b),(c,d)\bigr)\mid (a,b),(c,d)\in R\}$, where $R$ is the relation in the first paragraph....

Comment: @EricTowers thanks! It is not iff $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$?

Comment: Thank you very much! @EricTowers